Getting correct remote IP in nginx/docker-compose
I have a nginx image running in docker compose serving static files. I can see in the access logs that any hit to my domain will set the $remote_addr equal to the docker network's gateway IP instead of the correct client IP. If I curl to my server's IP, $remote_addr correctly reflects my IP. How can I get the client IP correctly assigned?
docker-compose.yaml
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    networks:
      - public

networks:
  public:

docker network inspect public | grep IPAM -A 9
"IPAM": {
    "Driver": "default",
    "Options": null,
    "Config": [
        {
            "Subnet": "172.26.0.0/16",
            "Gateway": "172.26.0.1"
        }
    ]
}

